# Unchecking 'part of a compilation' for multiple items in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

In iTunes, under the Artists list (brought up by ctrl+b in Windows), I have an unwanted 'Compilations' artist. In it are several tracks where the `part of a compilation`  box is checked when one goes to the `get info --> info` tab. I can go through individually and uncheck this, but when I select multiple items at the same time, this box doesn't appear in the info tab anymore.

Is there a quick way to uncheck this box for multiple items?

Comment: Does my answer below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Select all of the items and press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.  iTunes will ask you if you want to edit info for multiple items.  Select yes, then select the options tab.  There should be a dropdown menu on the right if the words "Part of a Conpilation."  Select yes, and then click apply, and you should be all set!

Comment: you're awesome, that works great, however I used CTRL i in windows!

Comment: On Windows in iTunes 11.2.2.3 for multiple selections its on the Options tab (not the Info tab like it is for single selections)